# Cefsharp webpage search

Tags: cefsharp

---

I would like to add search functionality to my page, with search_next, search_previous, search_close(clear selections) functionality along with this i would like to know the information about search_result_count, current_search_result_index. But there are only two methods exposed in CEF API:

```
public void Find(int identifier, string searchText, bool forward, bool matchCase, bool findNext);

public void StopFinding(bool clearSelection);
```

It seems like first we can do search_next and search_previous. 
I tried following for doing this and able to search backward and forward as expected but when i try to search other word then its not working:

```
private void previousMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ChromeView.Find(searchIdentifier, searchText, false, isCaseSensitive, true);
    }
private void nextMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ChromeView.Find(searchIdentifier, searchText, true, isCaseSensitive, true);
    }
```

And there is no method exposed to get search results count and current search index. I am using 41.0.1.0 version. Please guide me in right direction to achieve my requirements? 
Kindly don't mind my English;

Comment: @amaitland could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CefSharp.WinForms.Example` has a basic working implementation of `Find`.

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/43/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/BrowserTabUserControl.cs#L253

The `CEF API` documentation is http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefBrowserHost.html#Find%28int,constCefString&,bool,bool,bool%29

Comment: what about search word's count? and current search word index?

Comment: Neither are exposed by `CEF` to my knowledge. You might want to ask on http://magpcss.org/ceforum/ for clarification.

Comment: So it turns out there is a `CefFindHandler` interface which I think provides what your looking for. See http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefFindHandler.html#OnFindResult%28CefRefPtr%3CCefBrowser%3E,int,int,constCefRect&,int,bool%29
It's not yet implemented in `CefSharp`

Comment: I've created https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1459, contributions welcome!

Comment: Hey i want to contribute.. How can i proceed? I need your guidance.

Comment: Follow the issue above, you'll see it's already been implemented.